# Replacement for XDK "Publish" to ios/android stores feature

Tags: intel-xdk

Intel have just deprecated the [publish](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/publishing-apps-with-intel-xdk) feature of their XDK app. This is a shame as it allowed keeping app metadata, graphics etc in one place and used that to upload to both Google Play and Apple App Stores automatically.

Is there other software out there we can replace this feature with?

Comment: That really is a shame. I was using the XDK for a project last year (or maybe 2015) and that particular feature, I felt, was the most valuable part of it. It certainly wasn't the UI builder or god forbid that JS framework they included (and also made breaking changes to without a care in the world).

Comment: It's gone for good now. I always wonder if they could open source it and have someone take over or something.

Answer (score 0):

Not just this..
Apparently Intel have thrown quite a number of XDK users under the bus by deprecating the cloud builds as well.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-build-tab

I would stay away from this kind of "IDE's" in the future and rely on my own or community tools. So, to answer you questions - do it yourself from the starts, it's not that complicated. It's much more expensive to change the tools down the road.

Comment: Yes, it's just sunk in that I need to get a mac now to build for iOS, or use another cloud build service like Adobe Phonegap Build.

Comment: Yes, if you release for iOS then the common worse denominator is to run the builds on MacOS. Phonegap is better than XDK but also has its own problems - for example they don't support hooks. Interestingly enough there is no a reliable player on a market for this kind problem. I would gladly pay few bucks for a proper build system, yet it seems like a mission impossible these days.

Comment: I worked for months on XDK, using both the app designer and the cloud build. I have switched to Visual Studio with TACO for my Cordova development work. It doesn't build on the cloud, but it builds easily locally.